# Using split() on an element generated by for-loop with specific class

Tags: javascript, for-loop, split, var

I'm trying to define a variable that would contain the number of inputs generated by a `for-loop` that match the criteria.

I have this HTML (I've cut a lot of entries to make it more clear), where id and class are added in a loop (so the numbers after `block`, `string` and `item` are automatically generated):

```
<div id="blocks">
    <div id="block1">
        <input id="string1-1" value="3">
        <input id="string1-2" value="6:5" class="item1">
    </div>
</div>
```

The class is added when a specific criteria is met. Now, what I want to do, is to split each of the inputs with this class by the separator `:` they contain in their field `value`. I have the following, but it returns the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`:

```
var strItems = document.getElementByClassName('item' + k).value,
    arrayOfStringsItems = strItems.split(':');
```

I don't really understand what's wrong, as I already use the exact same syntax a bit earlier and it works:

```
var str = document.getElementById('tempString' + j).value,
    arrayOfStrings = str.split('*');
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eo0mxfxm/) if you want to try it out. As you can see in the console when you click on `Cut`, the problem happens on line 25/26, but a very similar line is used on line 5/6 with no problem. The only change is that it uses a `class` instead of an `id`, that should be possible right? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `document.getElementByClassName('item' + k).value` You can't get the `.value` of an element from the collection that it's in. Please read [documentation for `getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) *(And notice there's an `s` in the method.)*

Comment: +1 to the previous comment.

var strItems = document.getElementByClassName('item' + k)[0].value,
    arrayOfStringsItems = strItems.split(':');

Comment: also , you missed a 's' getElementByClassName -> getElementsByClassName

Comment: I see, thank you guys. Next problem is in split(): `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined ` : http://jsfiddle.net/eo0mxfxm/3